# Accessing Non-Related Form Object Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reform

Can I post data to the form object in a hidden form field that has no associated field in a database or param in a model using Reform?

I can pass the data to the controller fine when not using Reform (form object). But when I try and use Reform I just cannot seem to access it.

For example, `:name` would be a very simple thing using Reform;

```
<%= f.input :name, placeholder: 'Name' %>
```

But I need to pass in a list of IDs that I can run a validation on;

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :current_case_worker_ids, @case_workers.pluck(:id) %>
```

There is no `:current_case_worker_ids` really. That doesn't exist in my database (unlike `:name`).

Before Reform I was using `example[current_case_worker_ids]` to access the data.

Form Object;

```
class CaseWorkersForm < ApplicationForm
  property :case_worker_ids
  property :current_case_worker_ids, virtual: true

  def case_worker_ids=(case_worker_ids)
    binding.pry
```

So I would like to be able to access `:current_case_worker_ids` at the `binding.pry`

Comment: Can you post your form object?

Comment: Yeah it posts fine.. Or do you mean my code? I'll update now

Comment: So in your posted code there is evident typo, you have `case_worker_ids=` method and property is called `current_case_worker_ids`

Comment: It's not a typo. I also have case_worker_ids which are a collection of checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely caused by alphabetical order of properties. `case_worker_ids` is set before `current_case_worker_ids`, so when you try to access it in `case_worker_ids=` method it is not yet set. You should look for other solutions.

Comment: I have tried putting a_ in front of current_case_worker_ids. Doesn't seem to have made a difference. Is it a mass-assignment thing perhaps? (even though current_case_worker_ids) isn't related to a field in a database!

Comment: Try to add puts statements to both `current_case_worker_ids=` and `case_worker_ids=`. You will see what is the order of calling those methods.

Comment: Hmm.. a_current_case_workers_ids= didn't even appear in the terminal with a puts statement